# Parameter's modification in controller does not affect jsp rendering

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/page/{action}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(@PathVariable String action, @RequestParam Map<String, Object> param, PageInfo pageInfo, Model model) throws Exception {
    param.put("xxx", "123");
    return "/path/to/jsp";
}
```

The original value of "xxx" in param is "aaa". After `param.put("xxx", "123");`, the value of "xxx" in param is "123", but after rendering the value shown in page is "aaa".

Does the modification has no effect on jsp rendering?

Comment: Add the `Map` to the `Model`. `model.addAttribute("param", param);` take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646130/spring-web-mvc-modelattribute-and-requestparam-together

Comment: @jmcg Have tried, not working

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `@ModelAttribute` :

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/page/{action}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(@PathVariable String action, @ModelAttribute Map<String, Object> param, PageInfo pageInfo, Model model) throws Exception {
    param.put("xxx", "123");
    return "/path/to/jsp";
}
```