# Getting "null" value from bean when using @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is my Controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/email")
    public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@RequestParam("key") String key,@ModelAttribute(value = "quickbean") 
    QuickStartBean quickbean,BindingResult result,Model model) { 
        try {    
           System.out.println(key); 
           email=quickbean.getEmail();
           System.out.println(email);
           model.addAttribute("quickstartdatabean", new QuickStartBean());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I do not use `@RequestParam`, the code works fine and `quickbean` gets the form values but when I use it the bean gets `null` values.

How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646130/spring-web-mvc-modelattribute-and-requestparam-together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass key or not pass key it will work by adding `required` attribute , try to change with this `@RequestParam(required = false ,value = "key")String key`

Answer (score 1):

Every field in your `QuickStartBean` will be interpreted as `@RequestParam`.

So if you explicit use a `@RequestParam` in you controller method, spring will use it and ignores the `QuickStartBean`. Both the bean and `RequestParam` are not possible.

Put the `String key` in a `QuickStartBean`. Or create a new bean like this:

```
public class RequestForm extends QuickStartBean {

    private String key;

    [...] // getter,setter...
}
```

and controller:

```
public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@Valid RequestForm form, BindingResult result, Model model){
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        // return "error";
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `@RequestParam(value = "key")`.

Comment: this is the same like `@RequestParam("key")` value is alias vor `name`